# Font not rendering properly on WPF desktop application

Tags: wpf

I have a custom font in my project. But WPF is not rendering it properly.

```
<TextBlock Text="This is a test sentence" 
       Foreground="Black" FontSize="50"   
       FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/#Custom Font"/>
```

Now I have two font files named:

```
Custom Font Medium Italic.ttf
Custom Font Bold Extended Italic.ttf
```

When I open these two files, the font name shown is only Custom Font. In the above textblock, if I use full file name,i.e., Custom Font Medium Italic.ttf, it doesn't work. So how to use these fonts in the textblock differently.

Comment: What does it mean that it doesn't render properly? Distorted? Not at all? Wrong glyphs? Upside-down? Greek instead of English?

Comment: Text is not in the same font.Its like its not using the same font family which I have defined in Windows.Resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the name of the font and not the name of the font file. I think that you also need to add a `'#'` character as well... try something like this:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="testfont">Assets/Fonts#Custom Font Bold Italic</FontFamily>
```

From the [`FontFamily` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

**XAML Values**

*fontFamilyFolderReference*

> A string specifying a folder containing the font, along with a font family name. The folder and font family name are delimited by a # character. The folder reference may be absolute, or relative. For example, "Custom Fonts#My Custom Font".

Comment: But the font name is same, when I open the ttf file. What do you suggest then?

Comment: I don't understand... the font name is the same as what? It's *not* the same as the file name because the file name has a file extension and the font name doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the font files into different folders. e.g.

- /Resources/Font/Medium/Custom Font Medium Italic.ttf
- /Resources/Font/Bold_Extended/Custom Font Bold Extended Italic.ttf

then they can be referenced separately.