# Using Weather Icon Font in WPF Application

Tags: c#, xaml, unicode

I'm not very familiar with special chars, Unicodes, etc.
There is a very nice project:

[The Weather Icon Font](https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/) and I want to use it in my application, so I downloaded the font file, added it to my project and use the path as font family in a textblock

```
<TextBlock Text="\f002" FontFamily="Fonts/WeatherIconFont.ttf" />
```

But I did not get the expected item, also when I try to use *\u0f002* or *&#xf002*, so is it possible to use the font right this or in a similar way or should I go another one?

Thank you very much for all helpful and well meant answers in advance!

**EDIT:**

Indeed I made a mistake using the FontFamily in the TextBlock, I changed it to:

```
<TextBlock Text="\f002" FontFamily="ms-appx:/Fonts/WeatherIconFont.ttf#Weather Icons" />
```

But I don't get the expected item anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Font not rendering properly on WPF desktop application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046391/font-not-rendering-properly-on-wpf-desktop-application)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I followed the instructions right there, but my problem exists anymore

Comment: I need both, the path to the font file and #-seperated the font name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just like **\uf002** and everything is working as expected!

Thank you very much for all interesting and helpful comments!

Answer (score 2):

Seems this question was never clearly answered, so here's what I did.
The below implementation worked for me within my WPF application.

After adding the files for "*Weather Icons*" to the application via download package or Nuget, do the following.

**Step 1: Add Resource to your application/user control.**

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <FontFamily x:Key="WeatherIcons">/fonts/weathericons-regular-webfont.ttf#Weather Icons</FontFamily>
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

**Step 2: Add textblock control with the required icon code you desire and include resource added as FontFamily.**

```
<TextBlock Text="&#xf004;" FontFamily="{StaticResource WeatherIcons}" />
```

**Update** : If you plan on using bindings for these Hexcodes you'll need the below converter.

```
public class StringToGlyphConverter : IValueConverter 
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (value.GetType() != typeof(string))
      {
          return null;
      }

      string glyph = (value as string).Substring(3, 4); // for example: &#xe11b; will become e11b
      return (char)int.Parse(glyph, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you end up here searching for a solution for UWP (Windows 10), then  you should use the following:

```
  <TextBox Text="&#xf002;" FontFamily="ms-appx:///Assets/Fonts/WeatherIconFont.ttf#Weather Icons#Weather Icons" />
```